# How to extract response of OData in file uploading ?

Tags: sapui5

I am doing file uploading. I have uploaded file successfully. In the front end I am accessing er_entity from the back end by using uploadComplete event of FileUploader. I have wriiten function as below :

```
fnUploadComplete : function(oData){
        oData.getParameters().responseRaw;
    }
```

by using above function I am getting response but how to extract structure data I am not getting.

Thank,

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation for the uploadComplete method [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.UploadCollection.html#event:uploadComplete) specifies, the method
    **oControlEvent.getParameters.files** should provide with the response data

```
fnUploadComplete : function(oEvent){
        var aFiles = oEvent.getParameters().files; //Return an array with an entry for each file
        /*
        aFiles[0].headers -> Object with header data
        aFiles[0].fileName-> "Lighthouse.jpg"
        aFiles[0].responseRaw ->"Success"
        aFiles[0].status -> 200 //Status code, 200 is OK
        */
    }
```

Some parameters available previously have been deprecated since 1.28

Comment: What is your SAPUI5 version ?

Comment: In console it's showing ( sap.ui.version ) "1.42.9"   and in eclipse it's showing 1.40.11